# Prestashop Payment step template

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.6

I'm new in PS1.6 and I need to edit this page:

http://joxi.ru/brR83d7IXMPP21
Can you tell where I can find this .tpl file?

I have an image but have to use a link, sorry. Because stackoverflow sad so :)
(not enough reputation I've got :( )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a path to this template - /themes/..name-of-your-theme../modules/bankwire/views/templates/hook/payment_return.tpl

Hope this will helps to someone